# C++ speed up map access

Tags: c++, performance

I defined the following map:

```
class xy_angle {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int angle;

    xy_angle(int x, int y, int angle) :x(x), y(y), angle(angle){};

};

class xy_angleComparator {
public:
    bool operator () (const xy_angle &a, const xy_angle &b) const {
        if (a.x != b.x)
            return a.x < b.x;
        else if (a.y != b.y)
            return a.y < b.y;
        else if (a.angle != b.angle)
            return a.angle < b.angle;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

std::map<xy_angle, std::pair<int, int>, xy_angleComparator> transformed_coordinates_lut_;
```

I fill it up when I initialize the class that contains it:

```
//creating LUTs
int half_patch_size=48;
for (int x_start = -half_patch_size; x_start <= half_patch_size; x_start++){
    for (int y_start = -half_patch_size; y_start <= half_patch_size; y_start++){
        for (int angle = -314; angle < 314; angle++){
            float angle_f = (float)angle / 100.f;
            double cos_theta = cos(angle_f);
            double sin_theta = sin(angle_f);

            int x_tranformed = (int)(((float)x_start)*cos_theta - ((float)y_start)*sin_theta);
            int y_tranformed = (int)(((float)x_start)*sin_theta + ((float)y_start)*cos_theta);

            if (x_tranformed > half_patch_size)
                x_tranformed = half_patch_size;

            if (x_tranformed < -half_patch_size)
                x_tranformed = -half_patch_size;

            if (y_tranformed > half_patch_size)
                y_tranformed = half_patch_size;

            if (y_tranformed < -half_patch_size)
                y_tranformed = -half_patch_size;

            transformed_coordinates_lut_[xy_angle(x_start, y_start, angle)] = std::pair<int, int>(x_tranformed, y_tranformed);
        }
    }
}
```

And I access it using the following code:

```
int ax2 = transformed_coordinates_lut_[xy_angle(ax, ay, theta)].first;
int ay2 = transformed_coordinates_lut_[xy_angle(ax, ay, theta)].second;
```

I measured the map's access running time using a large set of random keys and it's quite insane. It totally dominates the running time of the functions that uses it.

It there any way to speed it up?

Thanks!

Gil.

Comment: Map is slow because AFAIK it quite often (if not always) is implemented as a binary tree. std::unordered_map should be faster. If you really need speed you could consider a sorted vector. IIRC the efficiency of several STL containers is convered [in this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs).

Comment: You may try a `std::unoredered_map` to get better performance on search.

Comment: are you saying the assignment of ax2 and ay2 are taking long or is it LUT creation? Also, your if statements can be simplified by assigning x_transformed and y_transformed together.

Comment: Also, unordered map are faster to access - if you have no regard for order in your design.

Comment: Do you need the map to be ordered?  If not, std::unordered_map has O(n) look up.  Other than that, you can toy with finding a better key, as well as calling reserve() which adds buckets and seeing if that changes max_load_ratio()

Comment: And be sure you aren't using a debug build while measuring performance. Even `operator[]` of `std::vector` can seem insanely slow then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a 3-D array instead: `f[x_start][y_start][angle]`. It would occupy the same(or less) space because you have all possible keys anyway. Of course, you can also emulate a 3-D array with a flat vector using appropriate indices. This approach guarantees you constant time lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of which container you use, this code is bad:

```
int ax2 = transformed_coordinates_lut_[xy_angle(ax, ay, theta)].first;
int ay2 = transformed_coordinates_lut_[xy_angle(ax, ay, theta)].second;
```

You're doing the same lookup twice! Definitely cache the result:

```
auto& a2 = transformed_coordinates_lut_[xy_angle(ax, ay, theta)];
int ax2 = a2.first;
int ay2 = a2.second;
```

Now as far as speeding up the work goes. The least work up front would be just to sub out a different associative container type:

```
using MapType = std::unordered_map<xy_angle,
                                   std::pair<int, int>,
                                   xy_angle_hash>; // implement this hash
```

That will give you `O(1)` lookup instead of the `O(lg N)` you are currently seeing in your code with `std::map`. But if you really want to spend a lot of time exploring this container, I'd suggest just wrapping it so you can control the implementation:

```
class TransformMap
{
public:
    std::pair<int, int>& operator()(const xy_angle& );

private:
    // is it std::map?
    // or std::unordered_map?
    // or 3D-array or vector or ... ?
};
```